# How can i put the text inside div above another specified div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day. I'm trying to create header section with bootstrap. But i'm facing a problem. Please check my script first

```css
#banner{
 background-color: black;
 height: 150px;
}

#banner p{
 color: white;
}

#Intro p{
 font-size: 12px;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="pull-right" id="Intro">
 <p>Customer Care | Login | Daftar</p>
</div>

<div id="banner" class="row">
 <div class="col-md-7">
  <p>asdfadsf</p>
 </div>
</div>



<nav class="navbar cstm navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
   
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

with my script above the position of `#Intro` is inside `#banner`. How can i put `#Intro` position above the `#banner` ?.  So the latest position is like this (From above) 1.`#Intro` 2.`#banner` 3. `.navbar` .

Thanks in advance.

My expected result [image]

Comment: What would be your expected result looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?I added `clear:both` in `#banner`

```css
#banner {
  clear: both;
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
}

#banner p {
  color: white;
}

#Intro p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="pull-right" id="Intro">
  <p>Customer Care | Login | Daftar</p>
</div>

<div id="banner" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <p>asdfadsf</p>
  </div>
</div>



<nav class="navbar cstm navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Code From

```
<div class="pull-right" id="Intro">
<p>Customer Care | Login | Daftar</p>
</div>

<div id="banner" class="row">
<div class="col-md-7">
    <p>asdfadsf</p>
</div>
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="text-right" id="Intro">
        <p>Customer Care | Login | Daftar</p>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div id="banner">
    <p>asdfadsf</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <div id="banner">
          <p>asdfadsf</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the pull-right class from the #Intro div.  It makes the div float, which breaks it out of the normal document flow.

Comment: Please read the question correctly. And check the expected output screenshot that OP posted.